# OSX bundler install command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm getting this error:

Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

When i try to run bundle install, i get this:

`-bash: bundle: command not found`

I have googled and tried to solve this for a while now with no hope. Please help.

Comment: Try `gem install bundler`

Comment: i get this : Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed , but when i try to run bundle install i get the same bundle command not found error.

Comment: on what OS are you running? are you using RVM or something?

Comment: on OSX mountain lion, and im using nothing just the command line

Answer (score 24):

Don't mess with your PATH.

Just use **rbenv** and **ruby-build** to manage and install your ruby version(s).

And then install the **bundler** gem and rehash.

Install rbenv (if you haven't already) as follows:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

Initialize rbenv as follows:

```
$ rbenv init
```

Install ruby-build to compile and install different versions of Ruby on UNIX-like systems:

```
brew install ruby-build
```

Install a specific ruby version, e.g., 1.9.3-p551:

```
$ RUBY_VERSION=1.9.3-p551
$ ruby-build $RUBY_VERSION $HOME/.rbenv/versions/$RUBY_VERSION
```

Verify it worked:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
```

Set that version to be the global/default Ruby version:

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p551
```

Install bundler:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.7.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.11
1 gem installed
```

Update rbenv:

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

Now, bundler will be available in the version of Ruby (1.9.3-p551) that you just installed.

Verify RubyGems Environment:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 551) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lex/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/lex/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/lex/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/lex/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/lex/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
     - "install" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - "update" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.rubyforge.org", "http://gemcutter.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
     - http://gems.github.com
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
     - http://gemcutter.org
```

Comment: Everything except `gem installed` worked on High Sierra. As a whole it is working without it.

Answer (score 10):

Seems with Sierra, you need to use this to get bundler installed:

```
sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4065) refers to how El Cap introduced "SIP (System Integrity Protection)."

Comment: This is actually the only proposed solution that worked for me (OSX High Sierra)

Answer (score 9):

try to run

```
gem env
```

and then you will get something like this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 448) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
  **- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/bin**
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/madhava/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Just add the executable directory to your PATH variable like this:

```
echo PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Reload your terminal to apply the changes and you will be set!

Comment: Helpful! When I ran `gem env` I saw references to `.rvm`, which should have been deleted since I was trying to move from rvm to rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

I am on `Mac OS X Maverics (10.9.2)`

Currently my `~/.profile` file reads as follows:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-23_at_17:28:39: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
. /sw/bin/init.sh
```

And my `PATH` variable (`$PATH`) is set to

```
/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

This is what worked for me.
First I installed bundler using:
`gem install bundler`

However I got error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Hence I ran `sudo gem install bundler` and that installed `bundler` successfully

After that when I ran `gem env` I got the Executable Directory set to `/usr/bin` which is already part of my `PATH` variable. Hence I didn't make any changes to ~/.profile file.

and now I am successfully able to run `bundle install`.

If the path listed in `Executable Directory` is not included in your `$PATH` variable or `~/.profile` file, you will have to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using rbenv, you should probably just `rbenv rehash` and not mess with your `PATH`